# ASP.NET Web API POST JSON data throttles CPU

Tags: json.net

IDE - VS 2012, ASP.NET 4.5 , Web API , Entity Framework 5.0

Test Environment: Windows 2008 R2 , IIS 7.5.7600.16385 , Application Pool used v4.0.30319, Classic Mode

We POST json data to it and it works fine in our development environment. However in our test environment we see that it sometimes goes haywire and CPU throttles 12% and slowly goes to 99%.

My understanding is that json parsing is failing and going into infinite loop. I am not sure how to trouble shoot it further.

Please can you give your input.

Below is the thread details that i captured using process explorer tool

```
Newtonsoft.Json.dll!Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.SetToken+0x0
Newtonsoft.Json.dll!Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read+0x34
Newtonsoft.Json.dll!Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.HandleError+0x5d
Newtonsoft.Json.dll!Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList+0x5c1
Newtonsoft.Json.dll!Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList+0x134
Newtonsoft.Json.dll!Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal+0x102
Newtonsoft.Json.dll!Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize+0x208
Newtonsoft.Json.dll!Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal+0x201
System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll!<>c__DisplayClass8.<ReadFromStreamAsync>b__6+0x2e4
System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously+0x78
System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll!System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.ReadFromStreamAsync+0xc1
System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll!<>c__DisplayClass1`1.<ReadAsAsync>b__0+0x34
System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll!<>c__DisplayClass41`2.<Then>b__40+0x46
System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.ThenImpl+0x114
System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll!System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync+0x2da
System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll!System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync+0x1e
System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync+0xe6
System.Web.Http.dll!<>c__DisplayClass1.<ExecuteBindingAsync>b__0+0x25
System.Core.dll!WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext+0x52
System.Web.Http.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.IterateImpl+0x87
System.Web.Http.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.Iterate+0x5a
System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync+0x1bc
System.Web.Http.dll!<>c__DisplayClass3.<ExecuteAsync>b__0+0x2f
System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.System.Web.Http.Filters.IAuthorizationFilter.ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsync+0x6e
System.Web.Http.dll!<>c__DisplayClass10.<InvokeActionWithAuthorizationFilters>b__d+0x2b
System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.ApiController.ExecuteAsync+0x1cf
System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsync+0x76
System.Net.Http.dll!System.Net.Http.HttpMessageInvoker.SendAsync+0x4f
System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpRoutingDispatcher.SendAsync+0x15d
CustomerUsageAPI.dll!CustomerUsageAPI.BasicAuthMessageHandler.SendAsync+0xa9
System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.HttpServer.SendAsync+0xff
System.Net.Http.dll!System.Net.Http.HttpMessageInvoker.SendAsync+0x4f
System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll!System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.BeginProcessRequest+0x11f
System.Web.dll!CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute+0x1e2
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep+0x120
System.Web.dll!ApplicationStepManager.ResumeSteps+0x208
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest+0x143
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal+0x3c5
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.ISAPIRuntime.ProcessRequest+0x202
[Unmanaged to Managed Transition]
[Native Frame: IL Method without Metadata]
clr.dll!DestroyAssemblyConfigCookie+0x1e825
clr.dll!StrongNameTokenFromPublicKey+0x30074
clr.dll!StrongNameTokenFromPublicKey+0x30012
[Managed to Unmanaged Transition]
[AppDomain Transition]
[Unmanaged to Managed Transition]
clr.dll!StrongNameTokenFromPublicKey+0x2fe06
clr.dll!StrongNameTokenFromPublicKey+0x2fc2d
clr.dll!DestroyAssemblyConfigCookie+0x1e783
webengine4.dll!IsManagedDebuggerConnectedIndirect+0x257
webengine4.dll!IsManagedDebuggerConnectedIndirect+0x70
webengine4.dll!SessionNDMakeRequest+0x17b
clr.dll!DestroyAssemblyConfigCookie+0x18f36
clr.dll!DestroyAssemblyConfigCookie+0x1834b
clr.dll!DestroyAssemblyConfigCookie+0x1824f
clr.dll!StrongNameSignatureVerification+0x5a22
kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21
```

Comment: Do you possibly have reference loops in your data?

Comment: Brian, sorry for being naive. Please can you elaborate it more. What do you mean by reference loops?

Comment: I mean objects that refer to each other.  For example, say you have an object A that has a reference to object B, and object B also has a reference to A.  Or maybe you have A -> B -> C -> A.  Depending on the serializer, it could go into an infinite loop trying to serialize that structure, because as it follows the references on each object, it ends up back where it started.  I think Json.Net is supposed to handle this situation, but if I were hitting an infinite loop during serialization, the first thing I would look at is the data.